# nginx CORS on proxy pass: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource

Tags: nginx, proxy, cors

I am moving my APIs from a subdomain to another without affecting already running applications. I have three servers configured on nginx such as:

Original API server:

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  example.com;

root  /var/www/example/;

index index.php index.html index.htm;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';

location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

 location ~*/api/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+) {
    proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:4343/api/$1;
    proxy_read_timeout 60s;

    proxy_set_header          Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header          X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header          X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' true;
 }
...
}
```

Proxy passed server:

```
server {
listen 4343;
server_name _;

root  /var/www/exampleapi/;

index index.php index.html index.htm;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';

location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
...
}
```

The AJAX call used to work perfectly on the old apis, however for the new ones I am getting an error on FF:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://example.com/api/startup. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' does not match '*, *').
```

And on Safari:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://example.com/api/startup. Origin https://myclient.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Curling on both new and old apis shows:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

How may I solve this issue?

Comment: Are you certain that browsers are getting the same response at curl is? Checking in devtools might be a good idea. Also, for a request with credentials, this is expected to fail. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Requests_with_credentials "when responding to a credentialed request,  server must specify a domain, and cannot use wild carding." See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743396/cors-cannot-use-wildcard-in-access-control-allow-origin-when-credentials-flag-i

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However if I disable credentialed request, I receive the same error.

Comment: And yes, the devtools show the same information. Even tried to set them both to example.com, and it showed on the devtools as (example.com,example.com) but still the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this was not to add add_header for CORS for the Proxy Passed server as this duplicates the header or to use set_header

Proxy passed server:

```
server {
listen 4343;
server_name _;

root  /var/www/exampleapi/;

index index.php index.html index.htm;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
...
}
```